# QGIS 3.22.7 - Trouble converting vector to raster (ERROR 1: Wrong value for -ts parameter)

Tags: qgis, raster

I am learning QGIS, and I have a series of polygons that I need to turn into a raster. The shapefile I am working with [can be downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bm5Yl9zqNVC58IuhYEgu3X9lDUXPXe7X?usp=sharing) (shapefile size is 3 KB). I am using the Rasterize tool, found by navigating to **Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to Raster)**.

My parameters can be found on the image below. Note that the "Output extent" is the  'qgis_question.shp' file, and I have the width and height resolution set to 0.5 meters because that is the size of the input polygons.

[image]

However, when I run the tool, I get the following error:

```
QGIS version: 3.22.7-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: 5a65627a
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.4.3
GEOS version: 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 9.0.0, March 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: 0a6ef5)
Algorithm started at: 2022-06-24T16:43:32
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 1, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '-96.462722339,-96.462674180,41.171721049,41.171734417 [EPSG:4326]', 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'data', 'HEIGHT' : 0.5, 'INIT' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\qgis_question.shp', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'UNITS' : 0, 'USE_Z' : False, 'WIDTH' : 0.5 }

GDAL command:
gdal_rasterize -l qgis_question -a data -ts 0.5 0.5 -a_nodata 0.0 -te -96.462722339 41.171721049 -96.46267418 41.171734417 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:\Users\Downloads\qgis_question.shp C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_QYaTKA/ec0d37a8fcdb47008b72df99d0be8d57/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:

ERROR 1: Wrong value for -ts parameter.
Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at] 
{[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add] 
[-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement] 
[-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* 
[-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]* 
[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height] 
[-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/ 
CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q] 
<src_datasource> <dst_filename>
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.06 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Temp/processing_QYaTKA/ec0d37a8fcdb47008b72df99d0be8d57/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/Temp/processing_QYaTKA/ec0d37a8fcdb47008b72df99d0be8d57/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

**How can I rasterize this layer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, you have selected Pixels for Output raster size units parameter. Therefore, by then entering 0.5 for height and width, you have asked for a raster of half a pixel by half a pixel, which obviously is not possible! If your output size is **pixels**, you must enter reasonable values for height and width which correspond to the number of **rows** and **columns** you want in your output raster (number of pixels). If you want to specify the output in resolution (size of pixels), you must select Georeferenced units for the output raster size.

Secondly, you are also assuming that you are entering 0.5 *meters*, but your shapefile is in a geographic coordinate system- EPSG:4326. So even using Georeferenced units, the values you are entering would actually be *Geographic Degrees*, meaning you would be asking for 1 pixel to be 0.5 degrees x 0.5 degrees. Since that is larger than your entire output extent, that is not going to work either!

If you want to keep working in WGS84 and using the same parameters, you would need to enter a *much* smaller value for output resolution. However, I would strongly recommend reprojecting your shapefile to a projected, meter-based coordinate system for your local area. You can either export your vector layer and save with a new crs, or just use the 'Reproject layer' algorithm from the processing toolbox and rasterize the output memory layer. Then you can work with meter-based resolution values.

Tested workflow:

I downloaded your shapefile and loaded into a blank project in QGIS. First, I changed Project CRS to [NAD83(HARN) / UTM zone 14N EPSG:3744](https://epsg.io/3744).

*Note: I'm not familiar with your local area, so I don't know if this is the *best* crs to use, but it seems like a reasonable choice.

Next, I used 'Reproject layer' from the Processing Toolbox and reprojected the qgis_question shapefile to the project crs (EPSG:3744), choosing 'Create temporary layer' as output.

Finally, I ran Rasterize (Vector To Raster) on the Reprojected temporary layer with the following parameter settings:

[image]

The screenshot below shows the resulting raster layer with the reprojected vector layer on top, symbolized with a transparent fill, showing only the polygon borders.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate you taking the time to provide me with a very thorough answer!

Comment: @s_o_c_account, no problem at all. I'm very glad you found it helpful!