# QGIS 3.28.9 - Unable to convert vector to raster: Raster is blank

Tags: qgis

I have a geopackage consisting of 16x16m squares, which hold data within them. I wish to convert said data into a raster format to be used elsewhere.
When rasterizing, however, the output file is blank, as all RGBA values are 0 and is showing the entire float32 spectrum (which is, again, blank).

I found a [similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434504/qgis-3-22-7-trouble-converting-vector-to-raster-error-1-wrong-value-for-ts) but their fix doesn't apply here. I also got suggestions that maybe the pixelsize I was going for was too large, but going smaller didn't help.
An alternative suggestion was made to take the centroids of each square and interpolate between the points. This is a horrible idea as it at times gives false values for certain areas.

The geopackage itself can be [downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1GsewB1urXQlfJM_pSt47d2lTcmceKVjE) if you're willing to give it a go.

Specifically I am trying to make it so that each 16x16 square is a single pixel. And the CRS is EPSG:5048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the geopackage format is causing a problem. If you export your file to a shapefile format and then open the attribute table, you will notice that the numbers in the V_MA field have very long decimal values.

[image]

Create a new field, name it `V_MA2` of type real, and decimal values equal to 2. Then, make a copy of the V_MA field using the field calculator.

Then, use the V_MA2 field to convert to raster.

Here is the information in the image below:

[image]

[image]

- Input file: test.shp
- Field to use: V_MA2
- Output raster size: Georeferenced units
- Width/horizontal resolution: 16
- Height/Vertical resolution: 16
- Extent: select `test` layer
- Output data type: Float32
- Rasterized: here, I used the `*.img` format

Here is the output raster:

[image]

Comment: Yup, this fixed the issue, Thanks!